# Display image from json in tkinter

Tags: python, json, image, tkinter, treeview

I have a treeview that lists the clients in a json, this json includes the path where an image is located. My problem is how to show the image in a label in tkinter. Currently it shows me the path of the image.

If I load the path out of the json it loads the image normally, but I don't know how to make it display directly when selecting the client from the treeview.

```
load = Image.open("example.png")
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
img = Label(self, image=render)
img.image = render
img.place(x=0, y=0)
```

Here is a sample of the code

```
import json
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.title("Test")
    self.geometry("1000x600")
    self.iconbitmap("img/favicon.ico")

    frame1 = tk.Frame(self, bg="green", height=300, width=700)
    frame1.grid(row=1, column=0)

    frame2 = tk.Frame(self, bg="yellow", height=300, width=700)
    frame2.grid(row=2, column=0)

    frame_entry = tk.Frame(frame2) #Frame para los entry
    frame_entry.pack(pady=20)

    tree_frame = tk.Frame(frame1) #Frame para el arbol
    tree_frame.pack(pady=20)

    #style del tree
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.theme_use("clam")
    style.configure("Treeview", background="#c7c7c7", foreground="black", rowheight=25,fieldbackground="#a1a1a1")
    style.map("Treeview", background=[('selected','green')])

    tree_scroll = Scrollbar(tree_frame) 
    tree_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
   
    json_tree = ttk.Treeview(tree_frame, yscrollcommand=tree_scroll.set)
    json_tree.pack()

    tree_scroll.config(command=json_tree.yview)

    json_tree['column'] = ("Logo", "Name", "Last Name", "Something")

    json_tree.column("#0", width=0, minwidth=0)#Columna Fantasma
    json_tree.column("Logo", anchor="w", width=120)
    json_tree.column("Name", anchor="w", width=120)
    json_tree.column("Last Name", anchor="w", width=120)
    json_tree.column("Something", anchor="w", width=120)

    json_tree.heading("#0", text="", anchor="w")#Columna Fantasma
    json_tree.heading("Logo", text="Logo", anchor="w")
    json_tree.heading("Name", text="Name", anchor="w")
    json_tree.heading("Last Name", text="Last Name", anchor="w")
    json_tree.heading("Something", text="Something", anchor="w")

    #color rows
    json_tree.tag_configure('par', background="#fff")
    json_tree.tag_configure('inpar', background="#d6d6d6")

    with open('prueba1.json', "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

        count=0
        for record in data['Example']:
            if count % 2 ==0:
                json_tree.insert(parent='', index="end", iid=count, text="", values=(record['Logo'],record['Name'],record['Last Name'],record['Something']), tags=('par',))
            else:    
                json_tree.insert(parent='', index="end", iid=count, text="", values=(record['Logo'],record['Name'],record['Last Name'],record['Something']), tags=('inpar',))

            count+=1

    #entrys
    l1 = Label( frame_entry, text="Logo")
    l1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    logo_lb = Entry( frame_entry)
    logo_lb.grid(row=1, column=0)

    l2 = Label( frame_entry, text="Name")
    l2.grid(row=0, column=1)
    name_lb = Entry(frame_entry)
    name_lb.grid(row=1, column=1)

    l3 = Label( frame_entry, text="Last Name")
    l3.grid(row=0, column=2)
    lastname_lb = Entry(frame_entry)
    lastname_lb.grid(row=1, column=2)

    l4 = Label( frame_entry, text="Something")
    l4.grid(row=0, column=3,)
    something_lb = Entry(frame_entry)
    something_lb.grid(row=1, column=3)

    def select_record():
        #Limpiar las cajas
        logo_lb.delete(0,END) 
        name_lb.delete(0,END)
        lastname_lb.delete(0,END)
        something_lb.delete(0,END)

        selected = json_tree.focus()
        values = json_tree.item(selected,'values') 

        logo_lb.insert(0, values[0]) 
        name_lb.insert(0,values[1])
        lastname_lb.insert(0,values[2])
        something_lb.insert(0,values[3])

    select_btn = tk.Button(frame2, text="Select", command=select_record)
    select_btn.pack(side=LEFT, ipadx=30,)

    def update_record():        
        selected = json_tree.focus()
        json_tree.item(selected, text='', values=(str(logo_lb.get()),str(name_lb.get()),str(lastname_lb.get()),str(something_lb.get()))) #guardar data

        columns = ("Logo", "Name", "Last Name", "Something")
        data = [dict(zip(columns,json_tree.item(iid,"values"))) for iid in json_tree.get_children()]
        with open("prueba1.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump({"Example":data}, f, indent=4)
        
        logo_lb.delete(0,END) 
        name_lb.delete(0,END)
        lastname_lb.delete(0,END)
        something_lb.delete(0,END)

    update_btn = tk.Button(frame2, text="Update", command=update_record)
    update_btn.pack(side=RIGHT,ipadx=30, pady=10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = App()
  app.mainloop()
```

An example of the json

```
{
    "Example": [
        {
            "Logo": "C:/Users/*/Desktop/Tkinter/imagel/face1.png",
            "Name": "Charles",
            "Last Name": "Darwin",
            "Something": "4"
        },
        {
            "Logo": "C:/Users/*/Desktop/Tkinter/imagel/face2.png",
            "Name": "Leonardo",
            "Last Name": "Da vinci",
            "Something": "7"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You already know how to show an image in a label, so what is your problem actually?

Comment: I know how to display an image in a label by putting the exact path, but the path of each image changes according to the item that is selected in the treeview. So, how can I show the image corresponding to the item that is selected from the list?

Comment: If you have the full path of the image (you get this when you select an item in the treeview), I don't understand why you cannot show it in the label.  You can use `.config(image=...)` to change the image of a label.

Comment: If the path appears in the entry of the logo, how would it show it? because the way I tried it was entering the variable of the entry in image.open. Something like this.

load = Image.open(logo_lb)
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        img = Label(self, image=render)
        img.image = render
        img.place(x=0, y=0)

if i use the entry variable logo_lb and add the .config to enter (image=) this would be equal to 'values'[0] which is the position of the data that shows me the path in the treeview? Something like this?
logo_lb.config(image='values'[0])